# How to return output of the new WordPress 5+ gallery block for automatically link images to media file?

Tags: wordpress, gallery, block, wordpress-gutenberg

I mange a multi-writers blog, and all our users uploading some gallery images, and they didn't know the difference between (attachment, media file or none). I found solution to hide the link panel, but I am editing all the published posts to change the gallery images link to file "manually".

[image]

Before WordPress version 5 I was linked all gallery images to "file" automatically by using this filter below.

```
add_filter( 'shortcode_atts_gallery',
    function( $out ){
        $out['link'] = 'file'; 
        return $out;
    }
);
```

But after WP 5+ how can I make it to work again? I really need to link all gallery images to "media file" automatically!

Comment: How you tried installing the old classic editor plugin, instead of Guttenberg editor?

Comment: Our users liked the new editor, so I'm search for solution to fix that.

Comment: Any hope to fix that!